# Java Card ECKey with NIST P256 Curve. How to encode a negative coefficient?

Tags: public-key-encryption, smartcard, javacard

I try to use an ECKey (http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/ECKey.html) with the P-256 curve defined by NIST on a Java Card:

```
Curve P-256

p = 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951
r = 115792089210356248762697446949407573529996955224135760342422259061068512044369
s = c49d3608 86e70493 6a6678e1 139d26b7 819f7e90
c = 7efba166 2985be94 03cb055c 75d4f7e0 ce8d84a9 c5114abc af317768 0104fa0d
b = 5ac635d8 aa3a93e7 b3ebbd55 769886bc 651d06b0 cc53b0f6 3bce3c3e 27d2604b
Gx = 6b17d1f2 e12c4247 f8bce6e5 63a440f2 77037d81 2deb33a0 f4a13945 d898c296
Gy = 4fe342e2 fe1a7f9b 8ee7eb4a 7c0f9e16 2bce3357 6b315ece cbb64068 37bf51f5
```

with y²= x³ -3x + b (mod p)

As far as I understand it I use

- p for setFieldFP(), prime p corresponding to the field GF(p)
- r for setR(), order of the fixed point G of the curve,
- b for setB(), second coefficient of the curve,
- Gx and Gy for setG(), fixed point of the curve (after encoding them as ANSI X9.62),
- cofactor of the order of the fixed point G is 1, so setK(1)

The coefficient A is -3 (according to the definition of the curve). But how do I have to encode -3 (as a byte[]), so that I can set it with setA()?

Comment: a seems to be missing in front of x**3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is easiest to look at existing libraries. P-256 is identical to secp256r1, and can be found in the Bouncy Castle source code. Alternatively, NIST has also published a document called [Mathematical routines for the NIST prime elliptic curves](https://apps.nsa.gov/iaarchive/library/ia-guidance/ia-solutions-for-classified/algorithm-guidance/mathematical-routines-for-the-nist-prime-elliptic-curves.cfm) which contain the parameters in hexadecimals. Thanks go to [this excelent answer on the OTN discussion forums](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11200243#11200243).

Code paste from Bouncy Castle, please respect the Bouncy Castle license.

```
/*
 * secp256r1
 */
static X9ECParametersHolder secp256r1 = new X9ECParametersHolder()
{
    protected X9ECParameters createParameters()
    {
        // p = 2^224 (2^32 - 1) + 2^192 + 2^96 - 1
        BigInteger p = fromHex("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
        BigInteger a = fromHex("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC");
        BigInteger b = fromHex("5AC635D8AA3A93E7B3EBBD55769886BC651D06B0CC53B0F63BCE3C3E27D2604B");
        byte[] S = Hex.decode("C49D360886E704936A6678E1139D26B7819F7E90");
        BigInteger n = fromHex("FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBCE6FAADA7179E84F3B9CAC2FC632551");
        BigInteger h = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

        ECCurve curve = new ECCurve.Fp(p, a, b);
        //ECPoint G = curve.decodePoint(Hex.decode("03"
        //+ "6B17D1F2E12C4247F8BCE6E563A440F277037D812DEB33A0F4A13945D898C296"));
        ECPoint G = curve.decodePoint(Hex.decode("04"
            + "6B17D1F2E12C4247F8BCE6E563A440F277037D812DEB33A0F4A13945D898C296"
            + "4FE342E2FE1A7F9B8EE7EB4A7C0F9E162BCE33576B315ECECBB6406837BF51F5"));

        return new X9ECParameters(curve, G, n, h, S);
    }
};
```

Note that `n` in this code is the order and `h` (of course) the co-factor. The seed `S` should not be required.

Comment: And notice the difference between the prime `p` and `a` of course.

Answer (score 3):

Since calculation is done modulo p, you are free to add p whereever you please.

a = -3 -> a= -3 + p -> a = p - 3